# Unittesting multiple projects with the same entity framework models

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

The situation is as follows:

I've got a solution with 3 projects

1. Services
2. Web
3. Unittests

In the web and services I've got a folder each which is named data and contains a MyEntityModel.edmx

Now I'm unittesting both the Services and the Web projects each. The tests work fine if I run them one by one (or just tests from 1 single project) BUT if I run ALL tests at once he does the first tests of the first project, but when he comes to the tests of the second project I get an error:

```
Test method MyProject.UnitTests.TExcelExport.TOfficeList threw exception: 
System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
he mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the 
EDM type 'EmployeesCumulated'. Previously found CLR type 
'MyProject.Services.Data.Employees', newly found CLR type 
'MyProject.Web.Data.Employees'.
.....
```

When I'm using the models I'm doing it this way:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)))
            {
                using (MyProject.Services.Data.MyEntities myEntities = new Swietelsky.WhoIsWho.Transfer.Data.MyEntities())
                {
                       List<Employees> employees = myEntities.Employees.ToList();
                       ....
```

What I've tried already is putting the whole namespace into the usings,.... but that doesn't work.

So my question is:
Is there any way to handle this so that the unit tests can be run all together (aka by clicking on the unit test project and clicking run all unit tests)?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new Project to hold your Entities. You would place 1 copy of the EDMX in that project and have that project build your Entities. Then Web and Service will reference that Project and have access to the Entities within.

An Added benefit of this approach is that you will only need to maintain 1 EDMX, so if you need to change your Entities you only need to do it in 1 place.